# How to Determine Cluster Count with Hierarchal Clustering

Tags: hierarchical-clustering

I have analyzed the following Data set in R using hierarchical analysis, and plotted the results. Ive been asked to find and highlight the number of clusters present, but how exactly do you determine this? It seems it all depends where you cut the plot at?

For example, with saying there are 5 clusters, you get something like this:
[image]

But with saying there are 2 clusters, you get something like this:
[image]

What is the right cluster amount, and how do you determine this?

Comment: The number of cluster is part of the output from the `cutree()` function.  It is easier to demonstrate if you can provide a sample of your data and code.

Comment: The `NbClust` package will compute 30 different indices indicating the "right" number of clusters. In many situations, the "right" number of clusters is related to what you are planning to do with the clusters. There is no guarantee that there is a unique "right" number of clusters for all purposes.